# CVS2SVN conversion failure due to Attic

Tags: csv, svn

I am using CVS2SVN tool(v2.5.0) running with python2.7 to convert cvs repository to svn. All initial validations are passed but get an error saying same file cannot contain in the actual path and Attic directory.

```
ERROR: A CVS repository cannot contain both c:\mycvs\programs\path\files\MyTest.java,v and c:\mycvs\programs\path\files\Attic\MyTest.java,v
```

How do I solve this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to correct the issue after reading more documentation and understands what is Attic and when it gets created. CVS creates the directory Attic and keeps the files which have two conflicting histories and even CVS does not know the correct history of those files.
Both solutions recommended by cvs2svn have pros and cons. You can use --retain-conflicting-attic-files to convert files in both places or remove Attic versions. I chose the second one and restarted the conversion.

Read here for more details
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~jacob/cvs2svn/faq.html